# split string a get distinct descendate values

Tags: java, algorithm

i have a result from database that return a string containing values, i want to get values from this string descendandly from a specif values. for example i getting query with value =`4762828`
and the result is this :

```
/2192519/863601/4762828/864056/
2192519/863601/4762828/864056/867339/
/2192519/863601/4762828/864056/867363/
/2192519/863601/4762828/864056/2201031/
/2192519/863601/4762828/864056/2201101/
/2192519/863601/4762828/
```

i only want to get the distinct values after the 4762828 downward `(864056,867339,867363,2201031,2201101)`

Comment: What have you tried and why does your program give you the wrong result? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i was eable to figure it out finally:

```
private Set<Long> get(String chemin, long id){
        String idOrg = String.valueOf(id);
        int index=chemin.indexOf(idOrg);
        String substr= chemin.substring(index+idOrg.length());
        return Arrays.stream(substr.split("/"))
                .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
                .map(Long::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    }

Set<Long> ids = new HashSet<>();
    stringsValues.forEach(fet->{
        ids.addAll(get(fet,id));
    });
```

Comment: This is exactly the [example] we asked for in "What have you tried ?".